# Comment étudier le français tout seul ?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Mon niveau est presque B1-B2 ([cadre CECR](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadre_europ%C3%A9en_commun_de_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence_pour_les_langues#.C3.89chelle_de_r.C3.A9f.C3.A9rences)). J'ai un bon vocabulaire (mais il pourrait certainement être meilleur), je me débrouille pas mal dans la compréhension, mais j'ai quelque soucis avec l’orthographe et la conjugaison, même si pour le moment ça n'est pas ma plus grande priorité.

Maintenant mon projet est de suivre une méthode (par exemple Alter Ego), mais elle n'est pas spécialement conçue pour les autodidactes et peut-être est-elle un peu trop « scolaire ». Y a-t-il d'autres méthodes plus adaptées pour les autodidactes ?

N'importe quel autre conseil sera bien accepté :)

Comment: C'est quoi un niveau B1-B2 ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI ça correspond à des niveaux définis il y a une dizaine d'années au niveau européen : [CECR](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadre_europ%C3%A9en_commun_de_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence_pour_les_langues). Le niveau B1-B2 correspond à un niveau intermédiaire, la personne pouvant être autonome et maintenir sans grosses difficultés une conversation avec un natif.

Comment: Merci pour le lien et l'info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il me semble que la meilleure méthode consiste à **lire** du français **quotidiennement**. La lecture apporte une intuition grammaticale et linguistique irremplaçable, permet de rencontrer de nombreuses expressions idiomatiques, renforce le vocabulaire, c'est on ne peut plus précieux.

Pour "personnaliser" le résultat, tu pourras souhaiter d'orienter le choix de tes lectures, soit plus techniques, soit plus classiques, que ce soient des journaux, des blogs ou d'autres types de textes, en fonction de ce que tu veux obtenir comme niveau de compétence au final. Le seul impératif étant de choisir des sujets qui t'intéressent pour ce qu'ils sont, et non seulement pour l'apprentissage de la langue. Tu es passionné d'écologie, d'histoire, de gastronomie ? (ou tout autre sujet) Trouve un ouvrage de référence, en français, sur le sujet et tu en bénéficieras doublement, pour la forme et pour le contenu.

Il faut bien sûr y associer de bons outils techniques (dictionnaires, ouvrages de référence grammaticale, de conjugaison, etc.)(par exemple ici : [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/)), mais il me semble que lire est au cœur du processus.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse. Enfait je lis et je regarde la télé. Et c'est vrai que ça aide, mais surtout la compréhension, un peu moins la capacité de s'exprimer (au moin pour moi).

Comment: @Paolo SE FL&U me semble alors un excellent complément pour la partie "expression"... Bon courage !

Comment: Having now done this for many years, I would recommend listening to French on youtube excessively too once you understand enough to do so. Otherwise you might end up able to read but not able to understand a word anyone says. :(