# French grammar resources without technical grammar terminology

Tags: grammaire, ressources

I'm a beginning learner and I'm looking for recommendations on a book or site with super-simple to understand French grammar rules.  The thing is a lot of sources say stuff like "like an infinitive in English"  but my English grammar is weak.  I learnt English grammar intuitively so I have no clue about the terminology which makes technical French grammar books confusing.  Any tips?  Is there a source that explains the English a little bit and then moves on to the French?

Comment: See http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17484/1995

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn the basic grammatical terminology in English, you can simply type, for instance, *infinitive* into this very trusted [dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/), and you will thus be able to read [a very simple explanation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/infinitive?q=infinitive) of the term you've been looking for.

Another site which explains, in very accessible terms, words such as *infinitive*, is this self-titled [glossary](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/).

Moving on to French, this [online grammatical compendium](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/French_Grammar.htm) may be the best starting point for any beginning learner like you.

And, of course, this site, where you will always have a decent explanation for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I like [french.about.com](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/French_Grammar.htm), but I prefer using a French grammar book. I propose 2 books which I use everyday along with my main *Café crème* textbook.

- [Practice Makes Perfect Complete French Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007178781X)
- [French Grammar For Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118502515)

C'est tout.

Comment: Is the Dummies because really good or just okay?

Comment: @verve I believe that it's okay just for starting French. By these kinds of books learners are able to know a way and use the experiences of others. I suggest that after beginning, when you understood the basics, start using a native French grammar book and also use these books along with a main textbook. As I said, I am participating in a French class that our main books are Café crème book series. Bon courage!

Comment: @verve:  My personnal feeling is that the Dummies one is not very good but you can [try it online](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/education-languages/languages-cultures/french.html) - won't have the sound of course.  You can also try the BBC [online course](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/french/) starting with [the beginners' course](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/french/talk/). Among the online free resources there's also [Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/), but all explanations are in French, even for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at http://www.frenchspanishonline.com it is free, there is a tutor to help you, you can drop him a line, many audio files and videos. The grammar part is really easy to understand and a ton of French expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a grammar-based approach without too many phrases such as "personal pronouns" or "infinitive" without reminder of what it is, then try:

- http://sapaacademy.net/french-lesson-1 (online learning portal that I'm building)

Lessons build on each other, and have:

- explanations
- audio
- practice texts

Give it a go.
Other sites based on "gamification" are: bussu.com, babbel.com, duolingo.com.

For flashcards I HIGHLY recommend quizlet.com.

Good luck! Learning a language is a long journey :) Enjoy it, don't force yourself!